# Show multiple fields based on dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to show / hide fields based on the drop down menu specifying 'other', however only the first element shows, how do I make all fields with li id = "osother" appear when selected?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Using Selectbox</title>
<style type="text/css">
#osother{display:none;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="otheros"){
                $("#osother").hide();
                $("#osother").show();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<li>
<p>Operating System: <Select Class="selectmenu" id="whatever" name="OS"              onchange="markDirty();" required>
    <option value = "">-- Select an Option --</option>
    <option value = "Win">Windows</option>
    <option value = "ios">iOS</option>
    <option value = "otheros">Other</option>
    </select>
</p></li>
<li id="osother">
Please Specify: <label id="oslabel"><input name="Other OS" type="text" placeholder="Other OS" size="50" /></label></li>
<li id="osother">
Version: <label id="version"><input name="OSV" type="text" placeholder="OS Version" size="50" /></label></li>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use ID only once in a document, so you have to change `#osother` to `.osother`. And also fields should be hidden when the value of dropdown is changed from `osother`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sodbileg/cqdnttn1/) is here.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>
    <p>Operating System:
        <Select Class="selectmenu" id="whatever" name="OS" onchange="markDirty();" required>
            <option value="">-- Select an Option --</option>
            <option value="Win">Windows</option>
            <option value="ios">iOS</option>
            <option value="otheros">Other</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</li>
<li class="osother">Please Specify:
    <label id="oslabel">
        <input name="Other OS" type="text" placeholder="Other OS" size="50" />
    </label>
</li>
<li class="osother">Version:
    <label id="version">
        <input name="OSV" type="text" placeholder="OS Version" size="50" />
    </label>
</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("select").change(function () {
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "otheros") {
            $(".osother").show();
        } else {
            $(".osother").hide();
        }
    });
}).change();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.osother {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: This has fixed my problem, thats very much. SW4's worked too, but this one changed back when selecting other options.  The issue I do still have with it is that when I have another select box underneath, it stops it from working.  The system I'm using marks these boxes up like this:

    <li><label for>NS - Additional Software</label>
    <select class="selectmenu" ID="_1_1_110_1" NAME="_1_1_110_1"   ONCHANGE="markDirty();">
    <option value="" >&lt;None&gt;</option>
    <option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
    <option value="No" >No</option>
    </select>
    </li>

Comment: @nbren007 I'm glad it has worked for you. If you have more problems, please ask new question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors here:

1. You need to encapsulate your `li` within `ul`
2. `id` needs to be unique- as it is assumed to be, the selector will only return on (the first) element, you should use e.g. a class instead, allowing you to select multiple elements within the same grouping
3. In your HTML you have capitalised `Class` and `Select`, these should be lowercase

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/s4beq095/1/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Operating System:
            <select class="selectmenu" id="whatever" name="OS" onchange="markDirty();" required='required'></select>
        </p>
    </li>
    <li class="osother">Please Specify:
        <label id="oslabel">
            <input name="Other OS" type="text" placeholder="Other OS" size="50" />
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="osother">Version:
        <label id="version">
            <input name="OSV" type="text" placeholder="OS Version" size="50" />
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "otheros") {
                $(".osother").show();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```