# Show multiple fields based on dropdown - doesn't work when other dropdowns are on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I previously asked about showing mulple fields based on a dropdown which used JQuery: 
[Show multiple fields based on dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200740/show-multiple-fields-based-on-dropdown#)

However when I have other dropdown fields on my page, this no longer works.  I did wonder it it was interfering with other JavaScript / JQuery elements, but removing those didn't correct the issue.  I've also tried putting the elements into separate ULs and DIVS with no luck.  Can someone help?

In my example, when selecting 'Taking over existing Mobile' it should display 'Existing Mobile No', however it won't when the 'Existing PC' is still listed on my page.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for>NS - Mobile</label>
        <select class="selectmenu" id="_1_1_81_1" name="_1_1_81_1" onchange="markDirty();">
            <option value="" >&lt;None&gt;</option>
            <option value="Mobile" >Mobile</option>
            <option value="Blackberry" >Blackberry</option>
            <option value="otheros" >Taking over Existing Mobile</option>
        </select>
    </li>

    <li class="osother">
        <label for>NS - Existing Mobile No</label>
        <input class="valueEditable" TYPE="text" name="_1_1_83_1" title="NS - Existing Mobile No" id="_1_1_83_1" value="[LL_FormTag_1_1_83_1 /]" size="12" MAXLENGTH="11" ONCHANGE="markDirty();">
    </li>

    <li>
        <label for>NS - Existing PC</label>
        <select class="selectMenu" id="_1_1_84_1" name="_1_1_84_1" onchange="markDirty();">
            <option value="" >&lt;None&gt;</option>
            <option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
            <option value="No" >No</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JQ:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "otheros") {
                $(".osother").show();
            } else {
                $(".osother").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

CS:
    .osother{display:none;}

My other JQ is here and collapses sections on the page - maybe irrelevant:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[LL_SUPPORTPATH /]core/jquery.collapsible.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
//collapsible management
    $('.collapsible').collapsible({
        defaultOpen: 'section1,section2,section3,section4,section5'
    });
});
</script>
```

There is also some JavaScript here and there that adds in TABS and Date dropdowns, but have tested without these elements and it seems still not to work.

Comment: You're using this `onchange="markDirty();` but where is this function declared?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/em0tgzqh/2/

Comment: Yes it is.  The onchange="markDirty();" is required on the form for the stage when it's passed back to our OpenText ECM system, so I have to have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you're looping through every `select` in the page and checking for their values, when you actually should observe just the one with ID `_1_1_81_1`.

Also, you can simplify your code:

```
$(function () {
    // Observe the particular select for changes in its value.
    // As every element in the page should have its on ID, you can
    // select it straight away (omitting the type - select). 
    $("#_1_1_81_1").on("change", function () {
        // Toggle the input visibility based on the selected value.
        // The .val() method works here just like for every type of
        // input. You don't need to go through all the select options
        // and test their values.
        $(".osother").toggle($(this).val() == "otheros");
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/em0tgzqh/3/)

[jQuery .toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

**Note:** This answer is based on the code you provided. If there are any other requirements or code involved, you should state it in the question.